# How do I run a Windows Terminal command from a shortcut?

Tags: windows-terminal

The same way you can echo "hello world" on cmd by creating a shortcut using `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k echo hello world`, how can I do the same with Windows Terminal? Swapping the cmd file location with the wt file location doesn't work. It says "/k was not expected."

Comment: HI, you might be confusing consoles and shells, have a look at this article: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-a-console-a-terminal-and-a-shell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to prepend wt.exe to that command, not replace `cmd.exe`. So the full commandline should look like:

```
wt cmd.exe /k echo hello world
```

That tells `wt.exe` to run the commandline `cmd.exe /k echo hello world`.

Comment: You just saved me a whole lot of time! Thank you so so much!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft PowerToys 0.79.0 has introduced the ability to remap shortcuts to launch applications in its Keyboard Manager tool.

Keep in mind you'll need to type in the path manually since the browser has issues accessing the "WindowsApps" folder it installs
into. `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe`